# SMTP Error could not authenticate and SMTP Error failed to connect to server(0)

Tags: php, email, smtp, phpmailer, gmail-api

I'm getting this SMTP error when using the newest PHPMailer release:

```
SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
```

I've tried using SSL instead of TLS with port number 465. OpenSSL is already loaded in the config file, and I've looked through the troubleshooting guide none of this has made a difference, what exactly is wrong with my code? One thing I'm not sure of is including the OAuth2 provider class with this :

```
use League\OAuth2\Client\Provider\Google;
```

There's no file path for that, should I change this? Also, when I change encryption to $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_SMTPS; and now I get this : SMTP ERROR: Failed to connect to server: (0).

Here's the code:

```
    class gmail_xoauth

    {
        public static function sendMail($subject,$body,$address)
        {


    $mail = new PHPMailer();
    $mail->isSMTP();

    $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_CLIENT;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
    $mail->Port = 587;
        $mail->SMTPSecure = PHPMailer::ENCRYPTION_STARTTLS;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->AuthType = 'XOAUTH2';

    //Fill in authentication details here
    //Either the gmail account owner, or the user that gave consent
    $email = 'myemail@gmail.com';
    $clientId = 'clientid';
    $clientSecret = 'clientSecret';
    //Obtained by configuring and running get_oauth_token.php
    //after setting up an app in Google Developer Console.
    $refreshToken = 'refreshToken';
    //Create a new OAuth2 provider instance
    $provider = new Google(
        [
            'clientId' => $clientId,
            'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
        ]
    );
    //Pass the OAuth provider instance to PHPMailer
    $mail->setOAuth(
        new OAuth(
            [
                'provider' => $provider,
                'clientId' => $clientId,
                'clientSecret' => $clientSecret,
                'refreshToken' => $refreshToken,
                'username' => $email,
            ]
        )
    );
    //Set who the message is to be sent from
    //For gmail, this generally needs to be the same as the user you logged in as
    $mail->setFrom($email, 'me');
    //Set who the message is to be sent to
    $mail->addAddress($address, 'John Doe');
    //Set the subject line
    $mail->Subject = $subject;
    //Read an HTML message body from an external file, convert referenced images to embedded,
    //convert HTML into a basic plain-text alternative body
    $mail->CharSet = PHPMailer::CHARSET_UTF8;
    $mail->msgHTML(file_get_contents('PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/examples/contentsutf8.html'), __DIR__);
    //Replace the plain text body with one created manually
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';
    //Attach an image file

    $mail->addAttachment('PHPMailer/PHPMailer-master/examples/images/phpmailer_mini.png');
    //send the message, check for errors
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Mailer Error: '. $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'Message sent!';
    }
    }
    }

This is the full error

    SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP w67sm7347917yww.16 - gsmtp
    CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
    SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [108.203.6.59]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
    CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
    SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
    CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
    SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [108.203.6.59]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-AUTH LOGIN PLAIN XOAUTH2 PLAIN-CLIENTTOKEN OAUTHBEARER XOAUTH250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250-CHUNKING250 SMTPUTF8
    SMTP Error: Could not authenticate.
    CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
    SERVER -> CLIENT: 221 2.0.0 closing connection w67sm7347917yww.16 - gsmtp
    SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
    Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/TroubleshootingEmail sent!
```

Comment: Leave the encryption settings as they are in the example code. Did you actually get the clientId and clientSecret values and put them in this script?

Comment: yeah I used the ones from the phpmailer github repo

Comment: ‍♂️ they won’t work - they are placeholders. Read the comments in the code you posted and the PHPMailer wiki article about using XOAUTH2 with google.

Comment: Yeah I've done all that now, and I got the refresh token and still get the same error

Comment: I've resolved this but now all emails go to spam instead of the inbox have you experienced this? I've tried allowing less secure apps on gmail etc. and I don't see anything to helpful out there